# Excel Attendance by Team

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of people by team that I am taking attendance for. There are multiple teams (A, B, C, D, E, etc.), and multiple users (Amy, George, etc.). Some members serve on multiple teams.

I am trying to take attendance for our meetings, and so I have a list of the person and multiple columns with dates for the dates they attended (Monday, Tuesday, etc.)

I want this attendance to be by person, but I also want a list that's by their team - so if any of the three people in team A attend on Monday, I want team A to have a "1" for Present for Monday. I need a way to lookup which team a person belongs to, even if they belong to multiple teams, and then to mark a 1 for Present beside the name of that team if ANY of the members of that team were present on a particular day.

Thanks!

[image: Image shows what my data tables look like, with mock data of course.]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58312000/edit) to include sample data, expected outcome, what you've tried so far and where the problem is?

Comment: Countifs() should work...

Answer (score 0):

If one has OFFICE 365, after `FILTER()` is released by Microsoft(currently only available to Office Insiders):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(B$2:B$6,1,$A$2:$A$6,FILTER($L$2:$L$9,$A13=$K$2:$K$9)))
```

[image]

---

Until then one would need to use this array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(B$2:B$6,1,$A$2:$A$6,INDEX($L:$L,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF($K$2:$K$9=$A13,ROW($K$2:$K$9)*{1,1})))))))
```

Being an array formula one must confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]